# disable call back query after one click on it telegram bot

Tags: php, bots, telegram

i have a problem using glass button callback query in telegram bot.that is that user can click more than one time and program failed because my program is step by step running and when click another time program goes to next step.
even when i delete callback message user can click more than one time
can you help me solve it? 
how can i disable that?

```html
<?php

else if(isset($arrayMessage['callback_query'])){
.
.
do some thing
.
.
.

}



?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you receive the callback_query, simply use [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) method and don't pass or pass blank string to `reply_markup` parameter

Comment: tnx for your answer.i think that has to be true. i will test it.just i have a question : i delete inline keyboard in this step after click on it and show next keyboard for next step.can i use it for my program?

Comment: You can definitely use the same method to make changes to the existing buttons or send new ones.

Comment: In case you want to make changes to the message text, then use [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext) method

Comment: tnx just i have one question how can i edit text of editMessageReplyMarkup ?
change options bot text not change

Comment: If you want to make changes to the buttons, then you need to create them again by using editMessageReplyMarkup method.

Comment: i mean how can change question text of editMessageReplyMarkup.

 . for example in first step i ask user to enter city and keyboard is name of city.in next step i ask them to enter their sex and keyborad is male and female. keyboard change truely but how to change text of the question?

Comment: Then use `editMessageText` method as mentioned above. With this method, you can also change `reply_markup`

Comment: tnx sooo muchh ;)

Comment: excuse me but my problem not solving yet :( when user multi clicking on each step calculated as multi step and not disable after one click on it

Comment: Those methods can be used whatever you want to do with the text or the buttons. If you can give more details about your problem, it can be helpful

Answer (score -1):

Simply set a flag that allows the user to click by default, and then craft a conditional that checks against this flag. Inside of the conditional, run the intended click behaviour, and then set the flag to false.

This can be seen in the following:

```
<?php

$can_click = true;

if ($can_click) {
  // Do stuff
  $can_click = false;
}
```

**However**, note that clicking is done client-side, so in order to disable clicking on an element, you're probably looking to make use of **JavaScript** instead of PHP (unless you're using something like AJAX to call the PHP script).

This would be done by crafting a function that is called on button click, and checking against a global flag, as can be seen in the following:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('click');
var can_click = true;

function clicked() {
  if (can_click) {
    console.log('This will only trigger once');
    can_click = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="click" onclick="clicked()">Click</button>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: tnx for your attention.but it has some steps and all of them needs call back query button how can i solve it?
after hide buttons in this step.shows buttons in next step

Comment: That wasn't stated in your initial question, and would be a job for JavaScript / CSS. Hide the button by default with CSS' `#button2 { display: none; }`, and then inside your function, you could do something like `document.getElementById('button2').style.display = 'block'`.

Comment: thats true for javascript but it is for telegram bot.
my bot works like this:1)shows some inline button.2)user click on it and it goes to next step.3)shows some other inline button....

but when user click two times it calculate 2 time and goes to next step

Comment: You can adjust the method of @ObsidianAge with `current_step = 0`. Where instead you check/change for true/false you increase the variable.

Comment: The question is about Telegram Bot API where you have no control over the UI. You can only interact by API methods. So, button click events are in now way like JavaScript.